# Replace whitespaces within a pattern

Tags: regex

I have variables(eg. `$!{Full Name}`, `$!{Full Na me}`) in a mail template(HTML content). Let's say. A mail template's content is: "Buyer name is `$!{Full Name}`. Age is 29." Before system stores a mail template, it needs to remove if any whitespaces within the variable. So, the output template will be "Buyer name is `$!{FullName}`. Age is 29."

For any below inputs the required output is Buyer name is `$!{FullName}`. Age is 29.

1. Buyer name is `$!{Full Name}`. Age is 29.
2. Buyer name is `$!{Full Na me}`. Age is 29.
3. Buyer name is `$!{ Full Na me}`. Age is 29.

Tried with:
`\$\!\{((?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*)\}` by replacing with `$!{$1}`

Since I need to implement this in Java, I can parse through the entire content and put these variables (eg. `$!{Full Name}`, `$!{Full Na me}`) in a list. Then after removing whitespaces, again put them back? Probably a solution. But, any alternative solution for this?

Comment: Please put at least some minimal effort into this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have tried.

Comment: @MaxZoom  I have to implement this in java. But right now I was testing in atom.

Comment: @hwnd  I have to implement this in java. But right now I was testing in atom.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have put my effort. Now could you help me on this?

Comment: Much better indeed. What went wrong in the attempt you showed? What is the actual format of your input? A file? A multi-line string? A list of strings?

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the language to get better help

Comment: So, you need a solution in Java? You know, you must always use the target environment to see if your solution works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the simplest solution is to match `$!{...}` strings and remove all whitespace inside them within a call to `Matcher#appendReplacement`:

```
String s = "Buyer name is $!{ Full Na me}. Age is 29.";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$!(\\{[^}]+})").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, "\\$!" + m.group(1).replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => Buyer name is $!{FullName}. Age is 29.
```

See the [Java demo](http://rextester.com/MFYJO71562).

The `\$!(\{[^}]+})` pattern matches the `$!` literally, then captures into Group 1 a `{`, followed with 1+ chars other than `}`, and then a `}`. Inside the `while` block, the whitespaces are removed with `.replaceAll("\\s+", "")`.

If you are a fan of a one-regex solution, you may use

```
(\G(?!^)|\$!\{)([^}\s]*)\s+
```

and replace with `$1$2`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0ZuL7Q/1).

See the [Java demo](http://rextester.com/BKRY91250):

```
String s = "Buyer name is $!{ Full Na me}. Age is 29.";
s = s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|\\$!\\{)([^}\\s]*)\\s+", "$1$2");
System.out.println(s);
// => Buyer name is $!{FullName}. Age is 29.
```

The regex matches

- `(\G(?!^)|\$!\{)` - Group 1 (this part will be kept with the `$1` backreference): end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or the `$!{` substring
- `([^}\s]*)` - Group 2 (this part will be kept with the `$2` backreference): any 0+ chars other than `}` and whitespace
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (that will be removed).

Comment: This is the solution I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps.

1. Get the substring between delimiters(**{** and **}**) -

   ```
   (?<=\{)(.*)(?=\})

   string : "Buyer name is $!{Full Name}. Age is 29."
   => subString = "Full Name"
   string : "Buyer name is $!{Full Na me}. Age is 29."
   => subString = "Full Na me"
   string : "Buyer name is $!{ Full Na me}. Age is 29."
   => subString = " Full Na me"
   ```
2. Now replace the whitespaces in captured substring using-

   ```
   /\s/g
   ```
3. Merge the original string and the rectified substring.